# How to set props in react native

Tags: react-native

I am using react native.
Here's my code.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    markers: state.markers,
  };
}
```

I set props using `mapStateToProps` and it only called when I dispatch an action.
I can set state using `setState({..});` like this.

Here's my question.
How can I set props? Is there anything like `setProps({..})`?

Comment: Set props for what? mapStateToProps allows you to select state from the redux store and injects that state into your component

Comment: Show us your reducer that handles the markers state and if you've made any actions for it.

Comment: Yeah, right. But is there anyway to change props without using redux?

Comment: My actions and redux works well. But I want to set my props manually without using redux.

Comment: Look at setNativeProps https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html

Comment: Can I set markers using setNativeProps? I think setNativeProps only used for set component props.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your question and what you're trying to do

Comment: Excuse me for my bad question. with mapStateToProps, I can change the markers. I think I have to dispatch an action for change markers because without the action, I cannot call mapStateToProps.  After changing markers, I can use this.props.markers.  What I wanna do is change markers without dispatch an action. Does it make sense? Thanks for your time.

Comment: you could just assign it to state and modify state instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155929/discussion-between-egor-t-and-linas-mnew).

Comment: I just wanted to modify props so that I can get different value when I am using this.props.markers. Is it impossible?

Comment: If it's impossible then I will create another action. Anyway, thanks for your time linas. I appreciate you!!!

Comment: It's wrong to update props without an action.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using Redux. If you do, make sure to have both reducer and action scripts. The reducer is used to get a value from a specific state property or properties.

You have to define a function in your action script to assign or set a value to your specific state property and properties. You also need a store to bring both reducers and actions together.

The store initializes everything and allows you to dispatch actions and set or get values.

Answer (score 1):

Two common ways of passing the props.

1. From Redux Store
   Like what you have done in your code.
2. From other Components
   Props can be passed by

`<Foo prop1={bar} />`

And in your Foo Component the props of prop1 is whatever bar is.

Comment: Is there anyway to change props byself in component?